# LogMeIn Hamachi "Network" menu gone in Lion

Tags: vpn

I have used LogMeIn Hamachi to play on different game servers, however since I update to Lion I have been unable to change the server I want to connect. The whole "Network" menu is gone.

Here is a video showing LogMeIn Hamachi in action, where the "Network" menu is visible: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bf2ttAWFrxg (See 1:20)

I have the latest version installed (2.1.0.65)

Comment: Just found out now that you have to click the connect button first and then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out now that you have to click the connect button first and then it works perfectly.